# High Contrast Scroll Bar in Browser

Tags: browser, scrollbar

I can barely see the Firefox scroll bar. I believe this is controlled by the operating system. I looked in Ubuntu Tweak > Miscellaneous but I don't see any color or contrast settings there.

How can I get a high contrast scroll bar?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in /etc/X11/app-defaults.  Many of the files have scrollbar colors set for applications. e.g. for the XTerm-color:

```
*VT100.scrollbar.background:    gray60
*VT100.scrollbar.foreground:    rgb:a/5/5
```

Change the VT100 to Firefox, change the colors to what you want, and put the lines into a new file /etc/X11/app-defaults/Firefox
Next time you start X, the new defaults should be present. (Haven't actually tried this myself).